# Cakephp 3.x => 4.0 migration: Fatal error in PHPStan\Analyser\MutatingScope

Tags: cakephp, phpstan

When I run the rector script `bin/cake upgrade rector --rules cakephp40 ../project/src` I get the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined property: PhpParser\Node\Stmt\ClassMethod::$attrGroups in phar:///Users/uscreen/Sites/upgrade/vendor/phpstan/phpstan/phpstan.phar/vendor/nikic/php-parser/lib/PhpParser/NodeVisitor/NameResolver.php on line 216

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in phar:///Users/uscreen/Sites/upgrade/vendor/phpstan/phpstan/phpstan.phar/vendor/nikic/php-parser/lib/PhpParser/NodeVisitor/NameResolver.php on line 216

Fatal error: PHPStan\Analyser\MutatingScope cannot implement PHPStan\Analyser\Scope - it is not an interface in phar:///Users/uscreen/Sites/upgrade/vendor/phpstan/phpstan/phpstan.phar/src/Analyser/MutatingScope.php on line 92
```

The script then exits with no changes made, but it echos `Rector applied successfully`. I don`t know where to start to debug this.

Comment: If I create a new app skeleton and replace the src and tests folders with the src and tests folders from my application, I can successfully run the upgrade rector commands. So I am thinking now, that the bug is somewhere in my app outside of the src and tests directories

Comment: You should just open this as an issue on Rector's GitHub.

Comment: But first try to upgrade PHPStan to the latest version.

Comment: I had a similar problem recently when I tried to upgrde from 3 to 4 using rector, one of the suggestions I found was to `rm -rf vendor` and then rerun `composer install` and then run the rector command again. This fixed it for me, might be worth trying?

Comment: @OndřejMirtes: do you mean PHPStan`s GitHub, or does Rector have its own github project?